c# bunifu material textbox does not appear
I installed bunifu.ui.winforms and bunifu.utils packages in the C# form application.
I need to add the "BunifuMaterialTextbox" element to the application, but only "BunifuTextBox" appears. I couldn't find the solution.
I installed the Bunifu license and trial version, but I still could not access the Bunifu material textbox
Bunifu Textbox screenshot
Bunifu Textbox screenshot 2
